# Show image of a Model in views Django Python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am developing an application with Python Django and I'm new to it, in models.py I have

```
class SubTypeModel(models.Model):
   importance = models.IntegerField()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SubTypeModelImage(models.Model):
    subType = models.ForeignKey(SubTypeModel)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "static/images/subtypemodels")
```

The admin.py is set properly and I can insert SubType with 3 different photos for each in database and photos are stored properly as well 
The issue is started when I need to show them in template in the template.html file I have

```
    {% for subType in all_subTypes %}
    <li>
        {{ subType.name }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

This can show the name of all the subType in database but I really have no idea how to show its photos as well

please help me how to add photos to view

in the views.py my query is like this :

```
 list_models = SubTypeModel.objects.all();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% for subType in all_subTypes %}
    <li>
        {{ subType.name }}
        {% for image in subType.subtypemodelimage_set.all %}
            <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" />
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can change `subtypemodelimage_set` to something nicer (like 'images') by setting the `related_name` argument on the foreign key field.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name